# How can I display the array result JavaScript I expected

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi here is my array generated

```
var iddate = value;
$scope.current_children[$scope.current_children_index].shift.push(arr);
resut:
     shift { 1: { 3045_20201123 : "AM" } 
             2: { 3042_20201123 : "PM" } 
             3: { 3041_20201123 : "AM" } 
     }
```

I expected to generate the value

```
shift
    { 3045_20201123 : "AM "
      3042_20201123 : "PM" 
      3041_20201123 : "AM"
    }
```

How can I generate the results I expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shift` is an array and you are pushing elements to that array. Instead, make `shift` an object and just assign the value to it.

```
var iddate = value;
$scope.current_children[$scope.current_children_index].shift = arr;
```

Supposing `arr` is the object that you want to keep. If not, clarify your question please.